# Is there a point to this site beyond data-hunt questions?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/174) asks whether we should have a specific tag for all questions of the form "where can I find open data about [x]"?

However, it appears to me that this is just about the only type of question that is reliably considered "on-topic" for this site. Of the top-rated questions so far, I see approximately three that are not data-hunting questions, and of those, [one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/42/174) already has four close votes. The [top question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/26/174) is quite good, but has almost as much to do with Creative Commons licensing as it does with data, and honestly I have no idea how many more of these types of questions this site could generate in the future. [This question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/145/174) does show the potential for questions related to tools for use with open data, but the question itself seems a little too open-ended to me, and most questions of the form "how do I use [this tool]" (which would be less open-ended) would probably be more appropriate for Stack Overflow (if it's a programming tool) or Super User (if it's not).

Beyond that, we've already had [several](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6/174) [discussions](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26/174) about what's off-topic, with the consensus frequently being "yep, that's off topic." (Although my answer to the latter question is the top-rated, the question I asked that partially inspired the question was closed.)

So my question is: can anyone explain what the potential for this site is beyond data-hunting questions? Can you give examples of hypothetical (or already-asked) questions that demonstrate this potential?

Answer (score 22):

> Can anyone explain what the potential for this site is beyond
>   data-hunting questions?

I'm very interested in this site for "process" type answers, like [Should I approach an agency unofficially before FOIAing them?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/42/should-i-approach-an-agency-unofficially-before-foiaing-them) and [What is the best way to request machine readable data from a FOIA request?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/171/what-is-the-best-way-to-request-machine-readable-data-from-a-foia-request).

There seems to be some disagreement over whether these questions are appropriate, but they also seem to have a high number of votes. They also seem to be very similar to appropriate questions in other Stack Exchange communities like [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/). For example [When to add fresh basil to a tomato sauce?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34015/when-to-add-fresh-basil-to-a-tomato-sauce).

I think it can be tough for people coming from StackOverflow where the "best" answer is one that compiles. Whereas here, I think the best answer is one that is both functional (tells you what to do), but also explanatory (tells you why it's done that way). Process questions have a little more wiggle room than code questions, but I still think they can be specific enough to provide real value to people coming to this community (especially organically through Google).

Answer (score 13):

One potential I see is "higher-level" questions, like [Open Data Scorecards?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/78/open-data-scorecards), a question about measuring and comparing openness of governments. Also under this category could be questions about legal means to overrule refusal of disclosure. I could even imagine people asking pushing forward open data movement.

Also, I'm interested in questions about **source** like:

[How can I trust the authenticity of an open data source?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-can-i-trust-the-authenticity-of-an-open-data-source/128#128)

How to verify the completeness of a list of something?

How to integrate data from multiple sources (say GDP figures of one nation from CIA, World Bank, and the Statistics Department of that nation)?

Answer (score 10):

I hope that there can be a place for questions that cover the work that often must be done to prepare 'open data' to support analysis or other uses.

While I agree there some questions for extracting and cleaning data could be asked on Stack Overflow, I think that these tasks are such a integral part of actually using open data that we will have both many users coming with these questions and a great depth of experience within this community in dealing with these data munging issues. I hope they can find a place here.

Comment: If it's technical questions about normalizing / homogenizing data, I could see arguing to put those on Stack Overflow or one of the other sites.  Questions about social and legal conventions for preparing a data release I would happily support here.  (and I might support the other ones, too, depending on how they're phrased .. remember, if you decided to be anal-retentive on the exclusivity, and we can't get the numbers up that SE wants ... they shut us down entirely ...  so trying to keep a walled garden might end up in no garden.