# Integration with Semantic/Web Data Community?

Tags: discussion

Hi Open Data folks,

we were just starting a [Semantic Web/Web Data/Open Data](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120833/semantic-web) community, and struggling with questions of names and scope, when we were pointed to the [beta Open Data community](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) here, which clearly overlaps in many ways.

So we were wondering how open the Open Data community was to allowing questions to be added with tags that were related to issues such as:

- Semantic Web Standards
- ontologies
- Access control on Data (remembering Tim Berner's Lee's presentation slide on [the data spectrum](https://theodi.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Screen-Shot-2018-02-27-at-12.42.42.png) at the ODI summit a few years ago, and authentication
- questions about publication of different formats and http content negotiation. Perhaps even issues relating to how HTTP 2.0 changes the picture
- mathematical logic issues with data
- implementation issues with libraries (if those are not better on stack overflow)
- Questions on Query languages.
- Perhaps even hyper-app development issues

Of course each of those would require a specific tag, as I suppose questions on all SE sites do, to help people follow their favorite subjects. I don't see a problem with being very wide in a SE forum, since Stack Overflow groups together people doing all kinds of languages, most of whose experts or engineers rarely interact (except perhaps through mathematical formulas and category theory).

How should one proceed to see if this forum or a different one would be better options? Should one even go so far as to create a much bigger forum that brings all IETF and W3C standads together (as [I suggested at least as a thought experiment](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28395/should-web-data-be-enlarged-to-cover-all-w3c-and-perhaps-even-ietf-standards))

Comment: you SW folks may recognize this [(inactive) user](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/401/jim-hendler?tab=profile) on OD

Comment: I've pinged a couple other OD people to add there thoughts to this thread...

Comment: See also: [Are (RDF) vocabularies/ontologies on-topic?](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/233/877)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's true that many (most?) of our questions are tagged as [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request), and many of those are migrated from [Stats.se](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), [Geospatial.se](https://gis.stackexchange.com/), and [DataScience.se](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), that tag is a huge outlier in terms of total question frequency. Here at OpenData we also have tags such as:

- [ontology](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ontology) (28 questions)
- [rdf](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdf) (28 questions)
- [sparql](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sparql) (34 questions)
- [linked-data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-data) (53 questions)

---

I personally think OpenData could use some new energy, so I'd be happy if new users from the Semantic Web community came onboard and shaped this site to meet their needs. I don't see really anything from the Semantic Web (or Web Data) site proposal that is "out of bounds", although non-data programming questions may still be better asked on Stackoverflow. Another thing to note is that we do like [tool-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-request) questions when they are related to open data, which is often not appreciated on other sites because the answers are usually opinion based.

---

Additionally, we could use 1-2 new moderators, so that would be a good opportunity for someone from Semantic Web to get involved.

---

update: some relevant, existing questions with good participation

[Any uses of JSON-LD?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/272/1511)

[What examples are there of Linked Data/RDF being used for open data applications?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/478/1511)

[What is the major difference between Open data and Linked data?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/522/1511)

[How to get my data accepted in the Linked Open Data Cloud Diagram?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3604/1511)

[Linked Data vs Linked Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/5182/1511)

[Linked Open Data Statistics](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/5851/1511)

Comment: I completely agree, we even specifically mention linked data, ontologies and related semantic technologies on our ["What topics can I ask about here?" help page](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: it would be extremely disheartening (and odd) to see a new mod taken from an area 51 and not from the few people here that keep the lights running.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I have semantic data or SPARQL questions, my first instinct is to ask at OpenData.

All of the bullets in the question above are already covered by OpenData, I would say.
Splitting forces would be a counter-productive.

"Only" 51% of the questions are [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request), which means 49% are about other open data topics, such as [releasing-data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/releasing-data) (114 questions), [metadata](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metadata) (75 questions), [wikidata](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikidata) (74 questions), [licensing](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing) (67 questions), etc.

I suggest you post all good questions from Area 51 to this site, and see whether they get closed as off-topic or not.

Comment: thanks for your answer. here are two new questions (definitely on topic, but no answers so far) 
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/13626/1511 
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/13625/1511